# How to export excel in Android?

Tags: android, export-to-excel

I want to export string or object to excel in Android.
And I don't have a good idea.
What should I do?
Please give me some suggestions about android export excel.

Answer (score 5):

1. Add gradle imports

> compile group: 'net.sourceforge.jexcelapi', name: 'jxl', version:
>   '2.6'

2. Add permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml file

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
> ```

3. Create new Class ExcelExporter:

   ```
   import android.os.Environment;

   import java.io.File;
   import java.util.Locale;

   import jxl.Workbook;
   import jxl.WorkbookSettings;
   import jxl.write.Label;
   import jxl.write.WritableSheet;
   import jxl.write.WritableWorkbook;

   public class ExcelExporter {

       public static void export() {
           File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
           String csvFile = "yourFile.xls";

           File directory = new File(sd.getAbsolutePath());

           //create directory if not exist
           if (!directory.isDirectory()) {
               directory.mkdirs();
           }
           try {

               //file path
               File file = new File(directory, csvFile);
               WorkbookSettings wbSettings = new WorkbookSettings();
               wbSettings.setLocale(new Locale(Locale.GERMAN.getLanguage(), Locale.GERMAN.getCountry()));
               WritableWorkbook workbook;
               workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(file, wbSettings);

               //Excel sheetA first sheetA
               WritableSheet sheetA = workbook.createSheet("sheet A", 0);

               // column and row titles
               sheetA.addCell(new Label(0, 0, "sheet A 1"));
               sheetA.addCell(new Label(1, 0, "sheet A 2"));
               sheetA.addCell(new Label(0, 1, "sheet A 3"));
               sheetA.addCell(new Label(1, 1, "sheet A 4"));

               //Excel sheetB represents second sheet
               WritableSheet sheetB = workbook.createSheet("sheet B", 1);

               // column and row titles
               sheetB.addCell(new Label(0, 0, "sheet B 1"));
               sheetB.addCell(new Label(1, 0, "sheet B 2"));
               sheetB.addCell(new Label(0, 1, "sheet B 3"));
               sheetB.addCell(new Label(1, 1, "sheet B 4"));

               // close workbook
               workbook.write();
               workbook.close();

           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. In your MainActivity add following method:

> ```
> private void askForPermission(String permission, Integer requestCode) {
>     if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(StartMenu.this, permission) 
>             != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
>
>         // Should we show an explanation?
>         if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
>                 StartMenu.this, permission)) {
>
>             //This is called if user has denied the permission before
>             //In this case I am just asking the permission again
>             ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(StartMenu.this, 
>                     new String[]{permission}, requestCode);
>
>         } else {
>             ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(StartMenu.this, 
>                     new String[]{permission}, requestCode);
>         }
>     } else {
>         Toast.makeText(this, permission + " is already granted.", 
>                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>     }
> }
> ```

5. Find a place to execute the export, for example in:

> ```
> @Override
> protected void onResume() {
>     super.onResume();
>     askForPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXST);
>     askForPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXST);
>     ExcelExporter.export();
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this **simple-excel**:https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android

Or **android5xlsx**:
https://github.com/andruhon/android5xlsx

They are trials to wrap and repack **Apache-POI** on Android. This'd be good starting if you are already familiar with **Apache-POI**.

I hope that may help,'.

Comment: Ok ,I will try it.Thank you.